# AWS Glue Crawler creates an empty table with tsv files, but not with semicolon-separated files

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have an AWS Glue Crawler with 3 data stores on S3, each data store is the S3 path of a table. The crawler works well when the files are semicolon-separated, while it breaks down when they are tab-separated.
However, according to the [AWS official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-classifier.html#classifier-built-in), the CSV built-in classifier

> Checks for the following delimiters: comma (,), pipe (|), tab (\t), semicolon (;), and Ctrl-A (\u0001). Ctrl-A is the Unicode control character for Start Of Heading.

Let me provide more details.

The S3 structure is as follows (all within the same bucket):

```
|--table_1
|---------|partion_a=1
|------------------|partion_b=2
|---------------------------|partion_c=3
|------------------------------------|partion_d=4
|-----------------------------------------------|file_1.csv
|--table_2
|---------|partion_a=1
|------------------|partion_b=2
|---------------------------|partion_c=3
|------------------------------------|partion_d=4
|-----------------------------------------------|file_2.csv
|--table_3
|---------|partion_a=1
|------------------|partion_b=2
|---------------------------|partion_c=3
|--------------------------------------|file_3a.csv
|---------------------------|partion_c=4
|--------------------------------------|file_3b.csv
|---------------------------|partion_c=5
|--------------------------------------|file_3c.csv
```

The crawler works as expected with table_1 and table_2, i.e. it creates 2 tables, it identifies the classification as csv, it creates 3 partitions, it detects the header.

While it doesn't work properly for table_3:

- it does create a table in the data catalog;
- it does add the partitions (all of them, i.e. partition_c = 3, 4, and 5);
- however **it does not detect the schema**, i.e. no columns at all

No errors are reported in the CloudWathc logs, while if I query table_3 on Athena (SELECT * FROM Table_3 LIMIT 10) I get the following error:

```
"HIVE_UNKNOWN_ERROR: serDe should not be accessed from a null StorageFormat"
```

These are the main differences among the table files:

1. Table_1 files are small, i.e. about 20 KB, and are semicolon-separated;
2. Table_2 files larger than Table_1 but still small, i.e. about 20 MB, and are semicolon-separated;
3. Table_3 files are much larger, i.e. about 200 MB, and are tab-separeted.

I have tried to rename table_3 files as .tsv and re-run the crawler, but nothing changed.
I have also tried using a single smaller file for table_3, i.e. only partition_c=3 and size about 2MB, but nothing changed.

Do you have any idea why this is happening and how to solve it?
Shall I create a custom classifier for the .tsv files only?

Answer (score 0):

In order to to create a TSV table and not ( comma (,), pipe (|), tab (\t), semicolon (;), and Ctrl-A (\u0001)) you need to create the table and schema defintion via AWS Athena editor query.

The component in Athena that is responsible for reading and parsing data is called a serde, short for serializer/deserializer. If you don’t specify anything else when creating an Athena table you get a serde called LazySimpleSerDe, which was made for delimited text such as CSV. It can be configured for different delimiters, escape characters, and line endings, among other things.

After you define the create table command and supply the table schema ,you need to add the following :

```html
...
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
...
```

Behind the scenes, when you see the actual table DML, you will see how it's parsing the data with the following regex:

```html
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'input.regex'='^(?!#)([^ ]+)\\s+([^ ]+)\\s+([^ ]+)\\s+([^ ]+)\\s+([^ ]+)\\s+([^ ]+)\\s+([^ ]+)\\s+([^ ]+)\\s+([^ ]+)\\s+([^ ]+)\\s+[^(]+[(]([^\;]+).*\\%20([^/]+)[/](.*)$')
```

Read more :

[LazySimpleSerDe for CSV, TSV, and custom-delimited files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/lazy-simple-serde.html)

[Working with CSV](https://athena.guide/articles/working-with-csv/)